# Is it possible to create SystemVerilog wrappers with modports for Verilog modules?

Tags: interface, system-verilog

Is it possible to create SystemVerilog wrappers with modports?

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface axi_if(input clk, input rst);
  logic arlen;

  clocking mclk@(posedge clk);
    output arlen;
  endclocking

  modport Master(clocking mclk, input clk, input rst);

endinterface
```

In the DUT wrapper I have:

```
axi_if my_if(clk, rst)

my_dut you_dut(.arlen(my_if.Master.mclk.arlen));
```

I tried doing this but I got a cross-module reference error. Any suggestions/clues what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate problems here.

1. A Modport is not a scope and you do not use it when accessing interface members through hierarchical references as if it were a module instance. You only use modport when connecting interface ports or virtual interface to limit access through the port. If your my_dut had an interface port, you could write `my_dut you_dut(.a_if(my_if.Master));` to specify that my_dut only has access to the interface signals specified by Master.
2. You didn't show if the my_dut arlen port is an input or and output, but it can't be an output port. That because the only thing you can do with `mclk.arlen` is drive it with a synchronous drive statement: `mclk.arlen <- expression;`. You cannot read it. So if arlen is an input port, you probably want to write `my_dut you_dut(.arlen(my_if.arlen));`.

Comment: Hi Dave, in that case how do I do a bind? Then it is not possible to do a bind of the interfaces with say _arlen_ (if needed by by someone else) because _axi_if_ does not have a port _arlen_